# Requisitos não funcionais de proteção

Tags: engenharia-de-software, requisitos

O código de verificação enviado ao e-mail, assim que a pessoa se cadastra em um site é um requisito não funcional de proteção ou de confiança?

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que é um Requisito Não Funcional de segurança pois, segundo a definição de Pressman:

> Requisitos não funcionais são os requisitos relacionados ao uso da aplicação em termos de desempenho, usabilidade, confiabilidade, segurança, disponibilidade, manutenção e tecnologias envolvidas.

PRESSMAN,R.S. Engenharia de Software 6a.edição, Editora McGraw-Hill,2006, ISBN: 8586804576

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!